# Oralce Query to pick the right record

Tags: sql, oracle

i have pondered about how would a select query be to pick the correct record based on the a certain quantity.

The sample table is as below

```
select b.*  from
(
    SELECT 100 as min_qty, '50' as price, '123' as itemfrom dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 150 as min_qty, '200' as price , '123' as item from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 200 as min_qty, '300' as price, '123' as item from dual
    UNION
      SELECT 50 as min_qty, '300' as price, '345' as item from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 150 as min_qty, '200' as price , '345' as item from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 300 as min_qty, '100' as price, '345' as item from dual

   ) b
```

so , the question goes what is the price if the item is 345 and quantity is 240 ?

sorry about my explanation , my english is not that good.

Comment: @TechDo appreciate making it more readable

Answer (score 0):

One option would be

```
SELECT price
  FROM (SELECT min_qty,
               item,
               price,
               lead(min_qty) over (partition by item 
                                       order by min_qty) max_qty
         FROM your_table)
 WHERE item = '345'
   AND 240 between min_qty and max_qty
```